# Extend the Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler.php inside package

Tags: laravel, lumen

I've got several Lumen services that have the same code inside the `render()` function within the `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` class. I want to move this code to a separate package that all of the services can include. I was able to get this working by making the package Handler.php file extend the `Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler.php` class, basically inserting my class between the default framework file and the Handler that users edit.

Change:

`class Handler extends Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler {...}`

To:

My class

```
use Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler;

class MyHandler extends Handler {...}
```

Framework class

```
use ServiceHelpers\Exceptions\MyHandler;

class Handler extends MyHandler {...}
```

However I ran into the problem where `Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler` doesn't exist when unit testing my file within the package. I've requires several `illuminate/...` packages in my composer file but it looks like the file I'm trying to extend is in the Laravel or Lumen framework and I'd have to require the `laravel/lumen` package which I don't think is appropriate.

I'm currently have the following required:

```
"illuminate/support": "^5.5",
"illuminate/http": "^5.5",
"illuminate/validation": "^5.5",
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically, your package depends on `laravel/lumen-framework` being installed, since it is extending a class from that package. Because of this, having `laravel/lumen-framework` as a dependency for your package is appropriate; your package depends on it being installed.

Comment: It's nice to know that that's ok. I was trying to include only the parts of the framework I needed but it does seem to solve all of the problems.